# git checkout branch causes detached head

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch

Trying to checkout a remote branch that does not yet exist on my system. For the purposes of this question, none of the 3 branches exist on my system.

`git branch -r` shows a list of relevant branches on the remote:

```
  origin/V2.0005B2
  origin/V2.0005B3
  origin/V2.0005B4
```

I can run `git checkout V2.0005B2` or `git checkout V2.0005B4` fine and it creates a local copy and sets it up to track.

But when I try to run `git checkout V2.0005B3` it puts me in a detached head state every time. It happens on every machine I've tried it on.

SourceTree can check out this branch just fine as well as git fork. But the Git bash command line has this problem.

I am only hoping there is nothing wrong with this branch, otherwise it seems to work fine as long as it is originally checked out using one of those other utilities. The branch lives in BitBucket and I've logged in there to see if I could see anything unusual, but it looks the same as the others.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a snapshot of the git message you get when it puts you in a detached head state. Also can you try using full refspec ,i.e., git checkout refs/heads/V2.0005B3 ?

Comment: `git checkout V2.0005B3 && git branch` ? Is `V2.0005B3` also a tag?

Comment: @pro_gamer: unfortunately, `git checkout` refuses to take `refs/heads/<name>` as a way of choosing a branch name. In this case the OP does not have that branch as a *branch* name yet, so it would not work even if Git *did* allow this syntax, but Git will treat a prefixed branch name like that as a `--detach` request, so it wouldn't work in both ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your local tags :

```
git tag --list
```

If you have a tag named `V2.0005B3`, running `git checkout V2.0005B3` will result in your situation : a detached HEAD state, on the commit pointed at by that tag.

- If you want to create a branch there, run :

```
git checkout -b V2.0005B3
git branch -u origin/V2.0005B3

# or shorter suggested by @torek :
git checkout --track origin/V2.0005B3
```

- If you want to delete the tag :

```
# delete your local tag :
git tag -d V2.0005B3

# delete the remote tag :
git push -d origin refs/tags/V2.0005B3
```

If this is a shared repo, tell all of your colleagues to also delete their local tag ; this will avoid surprising behaviors on their machine, and mitigate the possible reappearance of that tag on the central repo.

Comment: Yes that was it! I had no idea that tags hung around as references after you deleted the local copy of the branch.

Comment: edit : reworded my last paragraph ; I thought `git push` would push tags by default, but I was reminded that it doesn't. If the tag is present on the central repo, `git pull` does fetch the tag, though.

Answer (score 5):

[LeGEC's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67290752/1256452) as far as it goes, but I'll add two points.  The first is about how to get what you want, and the second, longer point, describes another failure case and yet another trick for working around it.

First, there is one more way to create a local branch from a remote-tracking name that is fairly short, and that is to use `git checkout` (or `git switch`) with the `--track` option and the remote-tracking name:

```
git checkout --track origin/V2.0005B3
```

This particular form locates the remote-tracking name (full spelling `refs/remotes/origin/V2.0005B3`), discovers that it is indeed a remote-tracking name (begins with `refs/remotes/`), applies the `--track` option to strip the `refs/remotes/origin` part to come up with `V2.0005B3`, and then uses the branch-creation option (`-b` for `git checkout`, `-c` for `git switch`) to create `V2.0005B3` with upstream `origin/V2.0005B3` already set.

Second: the usual reason for this problem is that Git finds the tag first, because there is such a tag:

- The `git checkout` code tries the name you give it first as the name of an existing branch—i.e., tries adding `refs/heads/` in front to see if the result will resolve to a commit hash ID.  If so, this is an *existing* branch name, and hence a request to switch to that existing branch.
- If that *fails*, however, it then turns to the usual six-step process described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which tries a tag name *before* a remote-tracking name.  Note that "try the name as a tag name" is step 3 (which comes before step 4, "try the name as a branch name": but `git checkout` did its own private step-4 before even going into the six-step process).
- Had there not been a tag, Git would have moved on to steps 5 and 6, and step 5 would have found the remote-tracking name.  This would invoke the "DWIM" code later to create the branch, unless you used the `--no-guess` option.  (This option was new in Git 2.21.)

But there is one more way for this automatic-creation `--guess` mode to fail, and that is if there are *two or more* remote-tracking-name candidates.  So if, say, there are both `origin/V2.0005B3` and `upstream/V2.0005B3` remote-tracking names, the guess mode does not know *which one to use*.

The `--track` option tells Git which one to use and thus neatly sidesteps this dilemma.  There's another trick, new in Git 2.19, as well: `checkout.defaultRemote` tells the `--guess` code in both `git checkout` and `git switch` which remote is *preferred*, if there are multiple matches.  So besides `--track`, if the issue is multiple remotes with identical branch names, you can configure a preferred remote so as to choose the *right* remote-tracking name.